# How to get all landmarks within a city Using Google Maps GeoCoding API?

Tags: api, google-maps

is there any way i could get all the landmark name within some few kilometers of given area. say for example there is a town called Bhatkal (5km in radius), which comes in Karnataka, India. As Bhatkal is just a small town google maps does not store all the geographical data, hence the feasible solution would be to store the nearest landmark's lat,long as listed in Google maps, for that i need to fetch all landmarks name within few kilometer radius, is there any Google Maps Geocoding API that support this? if not is there any alternative?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for // it looks really cool:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Comment: how to get all `point of interest` in google geo coding in particular city?